# Proper use of NSPredicate to retrieve data

Tags: ios, nspredicate

As is my very first attempt I would like someone to guide me and tell me what I am doing wrong. After several tutorials I've tried to create a mechanism that displays search results according user's input. App is searching in an array with multiple `Element` objects:

```
@interface Element : NSObject{

    NSInteger id;
    NSString *eName;
    NSInteger eCategory;
    NSString *eDescription;
    AddressBook *eAddress;
}
```

I am using the code below:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"(eName contains[cd] %@)",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [allElements filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

My problem is that, the results are not what I am expecting. It always returns `Element`s that their `eName` does not match the `searchText` but I have noticed that the given text it is appeared in `eDescription`!

How the above can be modified in order to look for the given text in eName of an `Element`?

Comment: Your predicate looks correct. Did you synthesize properties for the Element class? Perhaps an error in the @synthesize statement? - Also note that (as far as I know) there is no "b" modifier, perhaps you meant "CONTAINS[cd]"?

Comment: Or did you implement accessor methods yourself?

Comment: Hello, you are right about `cb`, I mis-typed it. About synthesise, no I do not synthesise properties. Didn't give me an error, so, I thought that would be fine. In addition, it returns results even without synthesise.

Comment: As you are probably aware, your object consists only of ivars. This must mean that KVC is accessing them through its means to access ivars directly. Have you tried instead to declare them as @properties (as alluded to in the questions about synthesize statements?) BTW, in that case, I'd ditch the explicit ivars in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hi. I've created property for each of my variables but the problem still there. I don't know if it is actually a problem or wrong manipulation. I want to search all elements and show these which their name contains the text in search bar.

Comment: After couple of hours of debugging, figured out that I was using the original array (instead of `results array`) for the results table! I am so sorry that waste your time. Thank you.